# Transfer of question from The Workplace to Academia?

Tags: discussion

Well the other day I was asking this question on The Workplace. However my gut feeling told me the question didn't really belong there, and they introduced me to this SE site instead.

Here's my question: https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/2152/whats-the-difference-between-a-bachelor-of-commerce-and-a-bachelor-of-science

Is this on topic here? Would I be able to get a transfer of the question from there to here? I'm looking at someone who has a general understanding of what each Bachelor degree does and which field of work hires them. Say for "Bachelor of Arts" it may include people who may end up being Creative Directors, etc.

Answer (score 1):

thanks for asking first on the meta! As it is, the question is off-topic, because  it concerns undergraduate studies, while Academia SE focuses on the graduate/post-graduate world. So, the only question you could ask here would be "What kind of Master/PhD program can I join with the following Bachelor degrees".

As for your question "what each Bachelor degree does and which field of work hires them", I'm afraid this is too general (a BA is to do something related to arts, and a BSc is to do something related to science ...), and it can varies from one country to another, one university to another, one department to another.

If you're interested in a particular cursus, you should directly contact the people in charge of this Master, and they probably can provide you with a brochure or some facts about what can you do after.

Good luck!

Comment: Right. As before this was written, I've already sent and email to enquire on what exactly do they provide for that certain course.